# Biological aspect of Artificial Intelligence

Tags: discussion

This might seem a bit opinionated, but since I joined AI.SE I have seen a lack of biological questions on this site. Neurobiology was one of the main influence of AI, but I don't see questions on the same. Questions on topics like brain, neurons, swarm-intelligence, etc. What can be done to explore the biological side of AI on this site?

Comment: That was brought up at P&N also: https://psychology.meta.stackexchange.com/q/128/19897

Comment: There's a few questions on our https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/machine-learning site, see also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_learning_in_bioinformatics

Answer (score 1):

Simple:

Ask more questions on the biological side of AI

That is pretty much it.

Comment: I get it...but we also need someone who will answer them...in short how can we diversify  our community more towards the linguistic and biological aspects..

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is my field. I'm researching the evolutionary development of human intelligence from non-intelligent roundworms. This is one part within the broader research on developing a general theory of intelligence and duplicating it non-biologically. This work seems to be unusual here since everyone else I've come across seems to assume that human reasoning is definable within Church-Turing.

I can't provide a lot of technical detail because it is unpublished and because it would take entire chapters to explain, but I can give general answers about what I know.

Comment: Keep visiting the site then..I had asked a few biological questions but the response to most of them was rather poor and computational based